# Successful Firestore Write Not Reflected in Data

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am expecting data for a document field to be updated via a setData (merge) write and it does not despite completing successfully. An updateData works, but I don't understand why setData doesn't work in this instance.

I am performing the following writes to Firestore and the following paths:

1. `setData` to firstCollection/uniqueDoc
2. batched `setData` to secondCollection/uniqueDoc1 (between 1-5 writes in batch)
3. transaction `updateData` to thirdCollection/uniqueDoc

No error prints out, all data and syntax appear correct, and #2 plus #3 writes reflect in the data successfully - #1 is the one that does not.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Here's my code for #1...

```
func first() {
    //oldData is not empty and is the same type as var updatedData
    //oldData = [
    //             "a": ["name":"aName", "dateAdded": dateValue, "imageUrl": "aImageUrl"]
    //             "b": ["name":"bName", "dateAdded": dateValue, "imageUrl": "bImageUrl"]
    //          ]

    guard let oldData = oldData else { return }

    var updatedData: [String: NSDictionary] = [:]
    updatedData = oldData
    updatedData["a"] = nil                       

    db.collection(firstCollection).document(uniqueDocName).setData(["data": updatedData], 
       merge: true) { error in
         guard error == nil else {
            print("Error:" , error)
            return
         }
         self.runOtherFunc()
    }        
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show what's not working the way you expect.  What exactly are you observing?  Is it different than what's expected?  Please be specific.  I suggest reading: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @DougStevenson I've updated my question! In short, a field is not updating via a setData write.

Comment: It doesn't appear anything in `func runSecond` or `func runThird` has anything to do with the actual question or issue so that should be removed as it's just excess code. We need to understand what kind of troubleshooting you've done as the code in `first` is incomplete. In other words, if oldData an an empty array, the code will 'run' but nothing will happen. Add a breakpoint here 'guard let oldData` and step through the code, inspecting the vars. Are they populated as expected? Add a `print(firstCollection` and a `print(uniqueDocName)` *before* the firebase function, what do they print?

Comment: @Jay thank you for the suggestion. i had added it because i thought it could provide contextual lead on what could be going wrong, like too many write procedures. that said, i've removed it. i've also checked that all the passed data, types, paths are correct.

Comment: Can you include a snippet of what your `oldData` Array contains? Also, can you update your question and explain what specifically you're trying to do? It looks like you're trying to remove a node and then write it back out? It's a bit confusing.

Comment: `updateData` "appears" to work or does it definitely work?

Comment: @Jay updated my question! i'm writing back an object that has been updated with a node removed

Comment: @bsod apologies, it does work.

Comment: Replace your data with dummy data that is of type `[String: Any]` and report back what happens. If the dictionary contains `nil` values, it would need to be `[String: Any?]` which you would then have to re-cast as `[String: Any]`.

Comment: To be clear, based on the commented sample in your question, */firstCollection/docName* has a child collection called *data* with two documents *a* and *b* and the purpose here is to remove documentId *b* (for example). Is that correct?